# PAce Arris home router port forwarding

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I am trying to enable port forwarding.

```
Manufacturer:   Pace Plc
Model:  5168N-110
Serial Number:  46181N003828
Hardware Version:   2701-000891-005
Software Version:   10.5.4.527631-sasktel
```

I created rules to forward port 3000 to a local IP address, the port is accessable from lan but it cannot be accesses from public internet.
Then I tried just to make the local machine the DMZ and now when i do an nmap scan from the local network it shows that port 3000 is open, however again it remains closed to public internet.

this is becoming really frustrating because i need to be able to forward ports to access resources from the internet for my job.

can anybody please tell me why i cannot open ports on the public interent facing side? making port forwarding rules seem to have no effect.

Comment: Are you behind a CGNAT? Thats one of the most common reasons port forwarding doesn’t work

Comment: when you are testing whether its accessible from the Internet, how are you doing that? are you on the LAN when you perform the test?